# Is it possible in Resharper to add a naming rule that allows different prefixes (wildcards)?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I have several *special* classes that have a naming convention like VLXXXX_NormalName.

Can I configure R# so it does not mark these classes as inconsistent? I've tried to specify the name prefix as VL*_  but it does not work:

[image]

Is this doable?

Comment: Silence... for years... so I suppose it is not doable. It is a pity, because it would be useful.